# Is there any way to force an "Allow Always" prompt to appear during onboarding in iOS13?

Tags: swift, ios13

I am working on an app that is very dependent on the user giving always permission. Since iOS 13 however, i can't force that while the app is in the foreground because there is no way for me to bring up a prompt for the user to select that setting through.

Looking around i found that there are many people complaining about the same thing and so far i have found no solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible, and even if you somehow achieve it technically, you will likely be rejected by App Review process:

From Apple Guidelines 5.1.1 (IV):
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

> (iv) Access: Apps must respect the user’s permission settings and not attempt to manipulate, trick, or force people to consent to unnecessary data access. For example, apps that include the ability to post photos to a social network must not also require microphone access before allowing the user to upload photos. Where possible, provide alternative solutions for users who don’t grant consent. For example, if a user declines to share Location, offer the ability to manually enter an address.

Some more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy